# CSS doesn't work on pages that have variables in their url

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I create a page where css works on every page except the page that is saved in the main.py file like this

```
@app.route('/sendKontakt/<nm>/<em>/<tx>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sendKontakt(nm, em, tx):
     return render_template('kontaktSucces.html', imie=nm, emile=em, wiadomosc=tx.replace("_", " "))
```

CSS doesn't work because url has <>.

The html code of this page looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}| Kontakt{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<h1>Dziękujemy za kontakt!</h1>
<p>Imię: {{imie}}</p>
<p>Emile: {{emile}}</p>
<p>Wiadomosc: {{wiadomosc}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

In base.html file header looks like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\css\style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel = "icon" href = "static/img/smallicon.png" type = "image/x-icon">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    
</head>
```

I apologize for not English words but they shouldn't get in the way of solving this problem.
Anyone know how to get css styles to work? I will probably not be able to write back for a few hours. Regards Kuba

Comment: URLs should use `/`, not `\ `: `static/css/style.css`

Comment: it still does not work.

Comment: I see: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static\css\style.css" type="text/css">` in `base.html`

Comment: I corrected, it still does not load css but only on this one page

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Your URL is relative. So if the page URL is `/sendKontakt/<nm>/<em>/<tx>` it will look for the CSS in `/sendKontakt/<nm>/<em>/static/css/style.css`. Use an absolute URL so it's not dependent on the page URL.

Comment: can you somehow import css into relative urls? I tried to paste<link> directly to the relative page file and it didn't do anything.

Comment: You don't import into urls. The URL says where the file is located. If the URL is relative, the browser will merge it with the URL of the page, and ask for that file from the server. So the relative URL has to be the correct location of the CSS file, relative to the current web page's directory.